# webbrowser component print qplot graph with an offset

Tags: c#, browser, jqplot

does anyone has an idea concerning the webbrowser component that always print jqplot graphs with a weird offset ?

This very simple exemple loading a jqplot exemple page in a webbrowser component, showes the page correctly, but when you try to print it you get an offset in the graph only.

The same web page show and print correctly from within IE !

I also tryied this exemple programed in Delphi2007 and DelphiXE3 and got exactly the same results.

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testwebbrowser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wb.Navigate("http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wb.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace testwebbrowser
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(597, 71);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 12);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "button2";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // wb
            // 
            this.wb.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.wb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 71);
            this.wb.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            this.wb.Name = "wb";
            this.wb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(597, 370);
            this.wb.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(597, 441);
            this.Controls.Add(this.wb);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb;
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the `delphi` tag, because your question has absolutely nothing to do with that language. Please use only those tags which actually apply to the question being asked. Thanks.

Comment: well, it hace a sence to have the delphi tag, because I first wrote this sample in delphi using the TWebBrowser component. Anyway, you are quite right, the bug is certainly in the component and not in the langage.

Comment: take a look at IViewObject Legacy Drawing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330732(v=vs.85).aspx#iviewobject_draw

Comment: I just had a look on those, but was not able to find one that solve my case !